# Avoid calling an object after it is dead

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a `threading.Thread` subclass in python and its run method is as follows:

```
def run(self):
    while self.caller.isAlive():
        details = self.somefile.read()
        if self.status() and details:
            self.handler(details)
        time.sleep(self.interval)
```

The arguments passed to this thread's `__init__` are as follows:

- `caller` is the thread object of the caller
- `status` is the callable that returns a boolean indicating the status
- `handler` is called to handle the details (some data)

The while loop checks if the caller thread is alive. If yes, it enters the loop and checks if it's time for a status update and handles the data. It sleeps and continues the loop. Note that in this case the `caller` is main thread and `status` is provided by the main thread (a function of some sort).

**The issue is** in between `while self.caller.isAlive():` and `if self.status() and details:`. If the caller thread gets terminated in that tiny fraction of a second, its `status` function would still get called and it will raise an error. Are there any ways to prevent this?

**Edit:**
The main thread invokes this thread. The main thread has the status function inside a class. Since it is a classmethod, the instance parameter `self` must be passed while calling it. In my case, it is like:

```
def OnStatus(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

When the main thread is exited (normally) the class object and it's instances are destroyed, but the thread that was started still persists and might call:

```
# self.status is self.OnStatus() defined before,
# it is passed as the status callable to init
self.status() # Things might go wrong here (at the wrong time)
```

**Edit**
Tried this with a wxpython application and there was an exception raised!

```
'The object that you are referring to is:'
<bound method TextCtrl.IsShown of wxPython wrapper for DELETED TextCtrl object! (The C++ object no longer exists.)>

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/test.py", line 37, in run
    if self.status() and details:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 9179, in IsShown
    return _core_.Window_IsShown(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: in method 'Window_IsShown', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow const *'
```

Comment: How is the caller thread getting terminated?

Comment: Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates your question. As it is, `status()` could be perfectly safe to call even when the caller thread has exited.

Comment: Just to expand on what @Robᵩ is saying, the caller `Thread` object won't disappear because its `run` method has finished, so you can still call `status()` on it. Now, if you're destroying some internal state required for the call to `status()` to work prior to exiting the `run` method, then you would still have issues. The easiest thing to do would be to just return `False` from `status` if the thread is no longer alive, and use an `Event` or something similar for the caller thread to signal that it's shutting down, so you avoid unnecessary time spent in `time.sleep`.

Comment: just put your logic in a function and wrap it with a try/except

Comment: @dano But the caller thread is the main thread and once it is destroyed altogether, the objects are no longer available for checking (or calling).

Comment: @user3058846 The main thread ending won't destroy the objects that the other thread holds a reference to. Try it yourself with a toy example.

Comment: @dano So, if this thread holds a reference to some function, and if that functions gets destroyed, what would happen if the thread calls it within the split second of checking its existence and actually calling it?

Comment: @user3058846 How would the function get destroyed? Python won't garbage collect something that has a reference count above zero. And the fact that your thread holds a reference to it means its reference count is above zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is stopping you from calling `status()` on the caller after the main thread has ended. The `caller` object will still be there. It stays alive because your background thread still holds a reference to it, which means its reference count is still non-zero. Consider this example:

```
import threading
import time

class Ok(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(Ok, self).__init__()
        self.obj = obj

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print self.obj.ok
            time.sleep(2)

class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ok = "hey"


o = Obj()
t = Ok(o)
t.start()
del o
```

We create an instance of `Obj` in the main thread, and explicitly delete the reference to it from the main thread just before it ends. However, our output looks like this:

```
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
<forever>
```

Because the background thread has a reference to the instance of `Obj`, it stays alive even though the main thread is finished.

Additionally, I would recommend using an `Event` to signal that the `caller` thread is shutting down, so that the background`Thread` will be woken up from sleep as soon as it occurs:

```
caller_dead = threading.Event()

def run(self):
    while not caller_dead.is_set()
        details = self.somefile.read()
        if self.status() and details:
            self.handler(details)
        caller_dead.wait(self.interval)

....
# This is the end of your main thread
caller_dead.set()
```

Comment: I've edited the question with a more detailed traceback

Comment: It says the object is deleted, even though the thread was referring that object's method.

Comment: @user3058846 Ah, you're dealing with an Python object that's wrapping a C++ object. Those tend to behave strangely with memory management. Things would probably work fine if you passed an instance of the `TextCtrl` to the background `Thread`, and stored a reference to it in the `Thread` instance, in addition to (or instead of) storing a reference to a function. That would keep the `TextCtrl` itself alive even if the main thread was dead.

Comment: @user3058846 Another option here would be to make the background thread a [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon), which would mean the background thread will be terminated the instant the main thread ends (assuming there are no other non-daemon threads running). This doesn't allow for any clean up before the background thread exits, but it looks like that might be ok for your use-case.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. I do have one doubt about daemon threads; are they ended abruptly? if a daemon thread that was writing to a file gets killed along with the non-daemon threads, will the file get corrupted?

Comment: @user3058846 Yes, daemon threads will get killed abruptly, and if they're writing to a file at the point they're killed, it could get corrupted. If your background thread is doing something like that, then you don't want to go the `daemon` route. The easiest thing would be to keep a reference to your object in the background thread in addition to the bound method.